# Is it possible to do a drop in a replacement for a wifi router?

Tags: home-networking, wifi-configuration, ssid

I'm thinking of switching ISPs and I would have to return my wifi router. I'm wondering when I get a new router, if I have my SSID and wifi password configured the same as my old router, would I have to reenter my wifi information on all of my devices?

Comment: I have been through this exercise several times. It's not that easy to transfer the settings between different makes of router (it all has to be done manually), but it's certainly possible and I've done it every time I've switched router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you configure the same SSID, WEP Key or WPA Password, then you should not have to reenter your network settings on your connected WiFi devices.  I have done the same through several routers with excellent results.  I also keep the subnet the same, although if your devices all use DHCP to gain their IP addresses, it should not be an issue.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is accurate!

Answer (score 2):

If it's the same SSID and Password then no you won't have to do that.

Comment: If *what* is the same SSID & password?  (Don't make the reader assume what you mean.)

Answer (score 1):

If your new ISP gives you a better rate and better bandwidth - By all means change ISPs.  Once you get your new router from the new ISP, it would be very wise to configure the new router's SSID and Encryption the same as the old router.  The reason for this is that you'll only have to configure one thing rather than multiple devices.  Since your devices already have a wifi profile configured for the old router SSID and Encryption, they will jump right onto the new router once it is configured.